# Calculate area of random polygon with specified 3D coordinates of boundaries

Tags: 3d, area, polygons

**Introduction**

I am a Belgian software engineer working in a company that is producing press brakes. I now have an interesting problem, where I would like to know the best solution, performance is really imporant in my working context. I think it might be interesting for other programmers/mathematicians as well.

**Data**

- I have a certain polygon, from which I know the 3D coordinates of all segments. A good example of what I mean is the following drawing I made by use of Geogebra online. Of course all segments are part of one 3dimensional surface, otherwise they would not be able to form a polygon.

[image: Area of random poly]

**Wanted**

I am searching for *a certain algorithm* to calculate the area of a random polygon, starting from the knowledge of the segments (which
   are all lines).

**Remarks**

- What I was for example thinking, was that any random polygon, I would be able to divide it in many triangles. That would allow me to calculate the area of those triangles and then simply add them to each other.
- I am just wondering if there are smarter or more performant ways to calculate this, as I will program such an algorithm in the code that I am working on a daily basis.

Comment: If I got this right, the whole thing lies in a single plane ? Your phrasing confuses me a little since 3D surfaces in general are not "flat". Anyway if everything is planar, project your coordinates in said plane, and use 2D methods. [This link should help](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html). If you want to try the method you've described, look up triangulation methods for polygons.

Comment: Hi @N.Bach ! Yes, correct, the whole thing lies in a single plane, sorry for confusing you. Thank you for your advice. I already solved this problem in the past year by using *XNAGeometry-code* to triangulate. It worked as expected.